# create trigger to update a table on inserting new row in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a **table X**,containing two fields **xID**,**xVAL**,

and another **table Y**,containing two fields **yID**,**yVAL**.

How can I create a trigger so that whenever a new row is inserted in table X,then for the xID and xVAL of the new row in table X,update table Y as follows:

```
     UPDATE Y SET Y.yVAL=X.xVAL WHERE Y.yID = X.xID;
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You're asking for a tutorial on how to make triggers? There are a million of them online. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: I couldn't find a proper answer for this specific question@shmosel

Comment: There's nothing unique about it. It's just a trigger. Maybe show us what you've tried and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON X
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Y SET Y.yVAL = new.xVAL WHERE Y.yID = new.xID ;
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If it's not, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41607446/edit) your question to include it.

Comment: its an answer @shmosel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.